# Retrieve records between two dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
select *
from emp 
where DATE_FORMAT(approved_date,'%d-%m-%Y')BETWEEN '01-01-2014' and '26-01-2014';
```

But it displays the records in the year of 2013.

Table is approved date:

```
01-10-2013
01-01-2014
25-2-2014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from emp 
where approved_date 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('18-01-2014', '%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('26-01-2014', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4d7e/13

Comment: thanks but i want to check date in dd-mm-yyyy format not in yyyy-mm-dd.is it possible?

Comment: great...it work... but insted of using STR_TO_DATE can we make changes  on this DATE_FORMAT(approved_date,'%d-%m-%Y') and get same o/p?

Comment: @user3057670 It is better not to use any function on the left side of the comparison because if there is a function used then MySQL will not be able to use INDEX (if any) and will result in slower performance.

Comment: @user3057670 yes, it can be done. Like this: `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(approved_date, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '16-01-2014' and '26-01-2014'`. Here is the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4d7e/19

Answer (score 1):

## [**MySQL STR_TO_DATE() function**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)

**dd-mm-yyyy format**

```
select * from emp 
         where approved_date > STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01','%d-%m-%Y') and 
               approved_date < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-25','%d-%m-%Y');
```

You can also use Between Too

```
   select * from emp 
             where approved_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01','%d-%m-%Y')  
                   AND STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-25','%d-%m-%Y');
```

## [MySQL STR_TO_DATE Function - Features, Examples and Equivalents](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date)

Answer (score 0):

**A Sample Example:**

```
SELECT users.* from users 
WHERE created_at >= '2011-12-01' 
AND created_at <= date_add('2011-12-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY)Which will select all users in the same interval You might also find the BETWEEN operator more readable:
```

or

```
SELECT users.* from users 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN('2011-12-01', date_add('2011-12-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks. But i want to check date in dd-mm-yyyy format not in yyyy-mm-dd.If i take %y-%m-%d then it work.but i want to check using dd-mm-yyyy format